# simulation of binomial distribution and storing value in matrix in r

Tags: r

```
 set.seed(123)
 for(m in 1:40) 
{

u <- rbinom(1e3,40,0.30)
result[[m]]=u 
}
result


for (m in 1:40) if (any(result[[m]] == 1)) break
m
```

m is the exit time for company, as we change the probability it will give different result. Using this m as exit, I have to find if there was a funding round inbetween, so I created a random binomial distribution with some prob, when you will get a 1 that means there is a funding round(j). if there is a funding round i have to find the limit of round using the random uniform distribution. I am not sure if the code is right for rbinom and is running till m. And imat1<- matrix(0,nrow = 40,ncol = 2)     #empty matrix
 am gettin the y value for all 40 iteration I Need it when I get rbinom==1 it should go to next loop. I am trying to store the value in matrix but its not getting stored too. Please help me with that.

```
    mat1<- matrix(0,nrow = 40,ncol = 2)     #empty matrix

   for(j in 1:m) {
 k<- if(any(rbinom(1e3,40,0.42)==1))             #funding round

{
 y<- runif(j, min = 0, max = 1)  #lower and upper bound

mat1[l][0]<-j
mat1[l][1]<-y                #matrix storing the value



}
}
resl
mat1
y
```

Comment: No need for `m++` or `next(m)`. This is not `R` syntax. Also `next` skips to the next iteration. In your case it's already at the end of the loop, so it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question:

```
result <- vector("list",40)

for(m in 1:40) 
{

 u <- rbinom(1e3,40,0.05)
 print(u)
 result[[m]]=u 
}
u
```

The second question is not clear. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: I made changes in the question, let me know if its clear? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

To generate 40 vectors of random binomial numbers you don't need a loop at all, use `?replicate`.

```
u <- replicate(40, rbinom(1e3, 40, 0.05))
```

As for your second question, there are several problems with your code. I will try address them, it will be up to you to say if the proposed corrections are right.

The following does basically nothing

```
for(k in 1:40)
 {
     n<- (any(rbinom(1e3,40,0.05)==1))  # n is TRUE/FALSE
 } 
 k  # at this point, equal to 40
```

There are better ways of creating a T/F variable.

```
#matrix(0, nrow = 40,ncol = 2)    # wrong, don't use list()
matrix(0, nrow = 40,ncol = 2)     # or maybe NA
```

Then you set `l=0` when indices in R start at 1. Anyway, I don't believe you'll need this variable `l`.

```
if(any(rbinom(1e3,40,0.30)==1))    # probably TRUE, left as an exercise
                                   # in probability theory
```

Then, finally,

```
mat1[l][0]<-j    # index `0` doesn't exist
```

Please revise your code, and tell us what you want to do, we're glad to help.

Comment: For the replicate I am not getting the desired, I need 1000 samples for 40 times. And for the 2 code by mistake, I used my old code. I have made the change in code if you change the probability it will give a different result. I did not got the last code suggestion you gave me at the last.